# Is it appropriate to ask questions about implementation of proof checker software on MSE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to ask questions about how to best implement algorithms for software manipulation of first-order logic formulas.  The algorithms would be written in pseudocode, and not specific to any programming language.

I'm not sure if this sort of questions should be posted on Math SE (where I would likely have access to experts with good understanding of first-order logic) or on a programming site such as Stack Overflow.  I would lean towards Math SE simply because the questions are heavily domain specific that only a person well-versed in first-order logic would be able to answer.

Comment: Still , being an expert in first order logic may or may not mean being able to answer an *implementation* question. If it involves some delicate programming choice, it still may be a question for a programmer. There are a lot of programmers with very advanced knowledge of math, you know. If it’s really about implementation and not the mathematics behind the implementation, it stilll might be better to try a programming site first, and come back here if that goes awry.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that